# Rails - Add index key for json parsed value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing, key

I am using `rails 4.0.2`. For my `mobile api`, I need to send `JSON` values to that. Here I face some problems to sending `JSON` . I want to customize my `JSON` with `index key`

For example, when I request `index` of my `cities` controller,

`http:localhost:3000/cities.json`

I got `JSON` value like this,

```
[
   {"id":1,"name":"AAAA"}, 
   {"id":2,"name":"BBBB"}, 
   {"id":2,"name":"CCCC"}
]
```

But I want to surrounded with some `named object` or `array`.

```
{
    "cities" :
    [
       {"id":1,"name":"AAAA"}, 
       {"id":2,"name":"BBBB"}, 
       {"id":2,"name":"CCCC"}
    ]
}
```

Now I tried in my controller,

```
def index
    @cities = City.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json{ render :json => @cities.to_json(:methods => [:image_url]) }
      # :methods => [:image_url] this is related to paperclip gem
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first as:-

```
def index
    @cities = City.all
    cit ={'cities' => @cities}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json{ render :json => cit}
    end
end
```

After that try as:-

```
def index
    @cities = City.all
    cit ={'cities' => @cities}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json{ render :json => cit.to_json(:methods => [:image_url]) }
    end
end
```